# Matlab Parse Error with a simple parenthesis?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to finish a program and for some reason, the matrix I loaded into Matlab is messing with the ability to select the rows inside it. I'm trying to select all the rows in the matrix and see which values match the criteria for a Live setting.  However I can select specific values/sections of the matrix in the command window without issue.  Why is this happening?  Any ideas?

It appears to only happen when in a for loop, I can do it just fine when it's on its own.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is: `for x = start:stop`. I think you are trying to do a for to the whole "A" matrix. You can split "A", according to its format (e.g. if is a table split in two variables).

bye

Answer (score 0):

Richardd is right on; you're trying to iterate on a matrix, no good.

If I read you right, you're trying to run through your `A` matrix one column at a time, and see all the rows in that column?  Assuming that is correct...

Your `A` matrix is 14x3, so you should go through your for loop 3 times, which is the size of your column dimension.  Luckily, there is a function that MATLAB gives you to do just that.  Try:

```
for iColumn = 1:size(A,2)
...
end
```

The `size` function returns the size of your array in a vector of `[rows, columns, depth...]`  - it will go as many dimensions as your array.  Calling `size(A,2)` returns only the size of your array in the column dimension.  Now the `for` loop is iterating on columns.